# Laravel 5.1: Null field being converted to blank in the function create

Tags: laravel-5.1, php-7

The Model.php has the following function:

`public static function create(array $attributes = [])
    {
        $model = new static($attributes);
        $model->save();
        return $model;
    }`

The `attributes` parameter has null value for each field when they are not filled by the user. However, after call `new static($attributes)` one field is converted to `""`. I do not understand. Even when all fields are null, only one field is converted to `""` (blank).

I do not want this convertion to blank. Anyone knows what is happening in this case?

Thanks.
Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem: In my `setPhoneAttribute` function (located in my Model class) I was calling a function to remove the format of the phone. So, as the phone field was null, after my removeFormat function the field is converted to `""`. Problem solved"!